# FN keys not working on an HP G62 laptop. Xev show nothing

Tags: 10.10, 11.04, shortcut-keys, multimedia, hp

From the just beginning my FN keys doesn't work. First i was using 10.10, than upgraded to 11.04 (clean install), but not answer from FN keys. Xev output nothing, when i press any of FN+key, also i had some multimedia keys, which both doesn't work.

I have HP G62 laptop. Can somebody help resolvse this?

Answer (score 2):

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Hotkeys/Troubleshooting has some hints for troubleshooting such keyboard problems.

Comment: Nothing. Tried every solution, but not output from FN keys.